# How to prompt for input in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have this procedure that follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Teleport` (INOUT sel VARCHAR(256), INOUT tar VARCHAR(256))
BEGIN  
    DECLARE self VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE target VARCHAR(100);  
    DECLARE tarpos VARCHAR(100); 



    SET self = (SELECT PlayerUID FROM player_data WHERE PlayerName = sel LIMIT 1);
    SET target = (SELECT PlayerUID FROM player_data WHERE PlayerName = tar LIMIT 1);
    SET tarpos = (SELECT Worldspace FROM character_data WHERE PlayerUID = target LIMIT 1);
    UPDATE character_data SET Worldspace = tarpos WHERE PlayerUID = self; 
END
```

I now want to Call the procedure, using CALL Teleport('Player A', 'Player B');

When the call query is run, -> "OUT or INOUT argument 1 for routine test.Teleport is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger" is the result.

Comment: That's really unclear what you're asking.. Are you asking how to call the stored procedure? or how to create one?

Comment: `LIMIT 1` should be inside the parentheses.

Comment: How to create, I want to create 'something', the user would run the procedure/function/query, and it prompts for user input. Which is then stored into two variables.

Comment: I don't think MySQL can prompt the user for input. The user should supply the parameters when they call the procedure.

Comment: `CALL Teleport('input1', 'input2');`

Comment: That I could do, have a method that I can call and they put information into the call statement, I don't know how to do that though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
OUT or INOUT argument 1 for routine test.Teleport is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger
```

It's really not clear exactly what you're asking, but the problem with the actual error you're getting is related to this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Teleport` (INOUT sel VARCHAR(256), INOUT tar VARCHAR(256))
                             ^^^^^                   ^^^^^
```

Stored procedure arguments can be `IN`, `OUT`, or `INOUT`.  The later two variants allow the value of the variable to be set (`OUT`) or read and set (`INOUT`) by the procedure.  You're calling your procedure with two string literals, 'Player A' and 'Player B'.

Using string literals as arguments is not valid with `INOUT` (or `OUT`, for an entirely different reason) parameters, it only works with with `IN`.

Since your procedure, as shown, does not actually modify the values of "sel" and "tar", there seems to be no reason to use `INOUT`.  Change that to `IN` and the procedure will not return that error.

On the other hand, if you do have a reason those need to be `INOUT` (which I doubt, but will explain in the interest of thoroughness), then the only way to invoke this procedure is to set the values into user-defined variables and use the variables as arguments (or use the `NEW` pseudo-row in a trigger, as the error indicates).

```
mysql> SET @p1 = 'Player 1', @p2 = 'Player 2';
mysql> CALL Teleport(@p1,@p2);
```